# Using JavaScriptExecutor in Selenium with Java - It takes the value but does not display it in the field

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Because of some of the things I am doing with my automation, I am trying to keep numbers as ints, text as String types,etc. WebDriver doesn’t “sendKeys” when they’re integers, so I did it using javascript. The first one I did was the credit card last 4 digits field, and I was successful with this line of code:

`jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('PaymentInfo_CCLast4Digits').setAttribute('value', '" + lastFour + "')");`

As you can see, by the dev tools and the firld, everything is as it should be.

[image: dev tools showing value for last 4 field]

Now, I also have a field called Quantity. Here is the jse code for that:

`jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('Quantity').setAttribute('value', '" + productQuantity + "')");`

And this is what happens:

[image: dev tools for jse version of quantity]

Now, as you can see, the value is 324, but it will not show up in the quantity field. BUT, if I change the variable type to String, and pass it through normal webdriver:

`driver.findElement(By.id("Quantity")).sendKeys(productQuantity);`

then it behaves as expected:

[image: Quantity from webdriver]

Does anyone know why this would happen? Here are the differences as I see them in the last 4 of CC field where it works with jse, and the Quantity field, where it does not:

1) Last 4 CC field is "type = text" where Quantity field is "type = number"

2) The Quantity field has those little up and down arrows, presumably because it's type = number

Anything else I'm missing? Is anyone else experienced enough with this to understand why 324 doesn't show up in the Quantity field when I send it with jse, despite the fact that the dev tools show that the value is indeed 324 and it does show when I send it through Webdriver as a String?

Thank you much!

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting!!
Can you please try

```
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('Quantity').value='324';");
```

I have tried it on a test page, For me the above code and setAttribute(as you are using) also worked fine. "324" should be typecasted to number in both the cases.

Hope it work for you.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow! That worked! And when I replaced 324 with thew variable '" + productQuantity + "' it STILL worked! I'm stunned and grateful! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Not a problem Buddy!